# Complete Bipartite Subgraph of Dense Bipartite Subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Q1: Consider a $2^n$ by $2^n$ bipartite graph with at least $(1-\epsilon)2^{2n}$ edges. For any $\epsilon > 0$ and $n$ large enough, is it always possible to find a $2^{(1-f(\epsilon))n}$ by $2^{(1-f(\epsilon))n}$ complete bipartite subgraph, where $\underset{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}{lim}f(\epsilon)=0$?

Comment: I suspect not.  Consider a matching of M 2^n edges.  Any complete A-B bipartite subgraph where the sizes of A and B add up to more than 2^n will contain an edge of M.  Now as n grows, 2^n will drop below the epsilon fraction, but the f(epsilon) will be forced to remain above 1/2.   Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.04.29

Comment: By the way, if this is homework, you should mention MathOverflow when using the above comment in your answer. Gerhard "Credit Where Credit Is Due" Paseman, 2013.04.29

Comment: Hi Gerhard, thanks for your reply! I did not understand why we should consider the case where A and B add up to more than 2^n. Also could you explain a little more why f(epsilon) will be forced to remain above 1/2?

Comment: I'm longing for Q2...

Comment: Patrick: take a complete (and balanced) bipartite graph with 2^2n edges, and color 2^n edges red when they are part of a particular matching. Pick a subset A of one side of the vertices.  What can you say about a subset B of the other side if B is such that there are no red edges between any member of A and any member of B?  Also, I would like to see some motivation for this problem.  It would also be good to know what type of class might assign this as a problem.  Gerhard "Will Know How To Answer" Paseman, 2013.04.29

Comment: Hi Gerhard, thanks for your response. This is not a homework problem but rather a problem that I came up with. The motivation of this problem is related to an engineering communication problem:
There are two independent inputs to a communication system (of size n), each input is a random number from $\{1,...,2^n\}$. The system is deterministic, it will output 1 for success and 0 for failure based on the input values. A certain algorithm guarantees that for any error threshold $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an integer n such that we can operate the system with error probability < $\epsilon$.  


Comment: The question is:

For any $\delta>0$ and n large enough, can we pick a subset $A\subseteq \{1,...2^n\}$ for input 1 and $B\subseteq \{1,...2^n\}$ for input 2 such that when the system inputs are drawn from sets A and B, the system will operate without any error. We also require $|A|=|B|$ and $n-\frac{\log(|A|)}{n}<\delta$.



Comment: Thanks for the motivation.  From the previous comment, given the subset A and matching M, calll A' the vertex subset "on the other side" of A that has red edges to any member of A.  Then there are no red edges between A and B precisely when A' and B are disjoint.  If you are now given an (otherwise) complete bipartite graph with a matching removed, you have only 1/2^n fraction of the edges removed, but any induced (bipartite) subgraph that is complete means that one side has less than half the vertices of that side.  Gerhard "Hope It Is Clearer Now" Paseman, 2013.04.30

Comment: Also, I am suspicious of your last requirement involving delta.  Supposing that you do not have n in the denominator, but just 1 instead.  Suppose further that I cause the system to error on the 2^n input pairs a,a only.  The only way to pick subsets A and B to avoid that error and have A and B of the same size is to have A and B be disjoint (temporarily identifying the input sets.)  This gives logbase 2 of size of A at most n-1, which means n minus that is always 1 or greater.  There is no hope when delta < 1 .  Gerhard "Does It Make Sense Now?" Paseman, 2013.04.30

Comment: Finally, like Francois, I also wonder about Q2.  Your brief preface (Q1:) is suggestive of homework. Gerhard "Does Not Wait For Godot" Paseman, 2013.04.30

Comment: Sorry for they typo in the last requirement, it should read $1-\frac{\log_2(|A|)}{n}<\delta$. Hopefully the question makes more sense now.
Thanks also for your intuition, I think you are right that it is unlikely for the requirements to be satisfied, since removing a small set of edges initially already cuts the size of $|A|$ by 1/2. However this is only true for the first removal, I have some trouble visualizing what happens as we remove more set of edges, since there are so many ways of picking sets A,B.
P.S. I wish there was a more interesting second question, now I feel silly putting Q1.

Answer (score 6):

No. The correct bound for the largest guaranteed balanced complete bipartite subgraph is $\Theta_{\epsilon}(n)$, where the implied constant depending on $\epsilon$ tends to infinity  as $\epsilon \to 0$, so it is only logarithmic in the total number of vertices.

For the upper bound, consider the random bipartite graph with parts of order $2^n$ where each edge appears with probability $1-\epsilon/2$. By Chernoff's inequality, with high probability, this graph will have at least a $1-\epsilon$ fraction of the pairs as edges, and a simple union bound over all possible $K_{t,t}$ with $t=g(\epsilon)n$ for an appropriate choice of $g(\epsilon)$ shows that this also will be $K_{t,t}$-free with high probability. This is essentially the same argument as given by Erdos in his classical lower bound on Ramsey numbers from 1947.

For the lower bound, suppose we are trying to show that there is a $K_{t,t}$. Then count the number of pairs $(v,T)$ consisting of one vertex from the first part and a set $T$ of $t$ vertices from the second part which are all neighbors of $v$. The number of such pairs is $\sum_{v}{\textrm{deg}(v) \choose t}$. One can lower bound this using the number of edges of the graph and Jensen's inequality. On the other hand, if there is no $K_{t,t}$ each $T$ is in at most $t$ pairs and hence the number of such pairs is at most $(t-1){2^n \choose t}$. One gets a contradiction to there being no $K_{t,t}$ if $t$ is too small.